# Caret hidden in UITextField (ios)

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have a simple application that has a few screens with things like buttons and uitextfields.  It is a navigation based application.  After certain time however, I can't see the caret when editing the uitextfields.  The editing works, but I can't see the caret (so I can't see what I am editing).  What can be the problem?
I see this behavior on iPhone 4S (ios 5.1) and iPhone 4 (ios 4.3.3), but on 4.3.3 when an alert is displayed, the caret is then shown on next uitextfield; on 5.1 the caret is not shown anymore.

EDIT: After the text fields are filled in, the application sends SMS by displaying MFMessageComposeViewController (presentModalViewController).  When the SMS is sent, in messageComposeViewController I am displaying an alert, saying "your message was sent, etc." and then doing dismissModalViewControllerAnimated.  When the alert is not displayed, the textfields are working fine (caret is visible); when the alret *is* displayed, the carets are no longer visible in text fields.  Why?

Comment: can you add some screenshots of your problem? (even if the caret is visible, just to give some insights into your textfield view setup)

Comment: actually, it is this app: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/union-mobilne-poistenie-cez/id443121517?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

What I did at last is to replace the alert by a regular (navigation) view controller, because I could not make it work; there was even no response to this problem on Apple's developer forum.